# PDO connections to old MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm pretty sure the answer is no but I really want to be 100% sure.

I am running a server using PHP v7.1.2 and Mysql V5.0.12. I connect to the DB using PDO and everything works great.

However, I have now been asked to query and retrieve data from an old server which has mysql V4.0.16. I have been told it cannot be upgraded and must stay on that version. The server is still in use so simply copying the data once isn't going to work.

I don't agree with the server staying on that version but that one is out of my control.

When I attempt to connect I get the following:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0  is not supported. Server is 4.0.16

I know automating replication is a no go between the two versions.

Any support in getting a connection working would be great. If the answer is simply no, then at least I can put it to rest and move on to the next challenge.

Comment: `PDO_MYSQL is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to MySQL 3.x, 4.x and 5.x databases. `

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have just updated the question to include the error which has led me down the path of it not being possible. I'm reading the link you posted as well.

Comment: Authentication protocol changed after MySQL/4. I suspect you may need to downgrade the MySQL client libraries but I'm not sure that's possible if you don't downgrade PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for the info. Its appreciated. Whilst that's a possibility I really don't want to go backwards on my server to allow for outdated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses.

As I am not able to upgrade the version of MySQL I went on the hunt for other options.

For anyone else who may encounter this here is what i did:

1. Use html and java to post key variables from my new server to the old one using a redirect.

   `<form id="myForm" action="http://anotheraddress/mypage.php" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo $foo ?>">';
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
   </script>`
2. Run the queries on the old server using the older version of PHP
3. Post them back to the new one in the same way as step 1
4. Carry on as normal with my data